# Neo4j Refused to Connect on Ubuntu Server

Tags: neo4j

I have been using Neo4j on a ubuntu server for months, but I downloaded the dependencies for apoc.mongodb a few days ago, then restarted Neo4j following the instructions [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.mongodb/apoc.mongodb.first/). I no longer can connect to Neo4j since I did this! I tried the browser and the shell. In both cases, I get "connection refused". The configuration file is the same, and nothing changed at all. I can't find any explanation for this!

Here is some detailed info that may be needed:

Neo4j version: 4.4.4
The command to restart neo4j: sudo systemctl restart neo4j.service
The network configurations:
dbms.default_listen_address=  (I also tried 0.0.0.0)

Bolt connector:

dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true

dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=DISABLED

dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:0.0.0.0:7687

#dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=:7687

HTTP Connector:

dbms.connector.http.enabled=true

dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474

#dbms.connector.http.advertised_address=:7474

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

check /var/log/neo4j/debug.log for error messages (perhaps you miss an extra dependency),

Try to remove the mongodb procs again and see if it starts up.

If you can please share the logs in a GitHub issue in

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues